# Cannot get data from real time database with anonymous authentication (React Native) - Permission Denied

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to implement anonymous authentication in my app. I have done it with React Native Firebase (https://rnfirebase.io/). So far the sign up is good. The user signs up and I get a user id for that particular case. This is my code for it:

```
const authenticate = async () => {
    await auth()
      .signInAnonymously()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('User signed in anonymously');
        console.log(user);
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user != null) {
            fetchData();
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.code === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
          console.log('Enable anonymous in your firebase console.');
        }
        setFetching(false);
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

As you can see, if you check the part when the sign up is successful, we have a function called fetchData(). This function retrieved my data form the real time database. Here it is:

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch(setLocale())
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => {
          saveFavoritesFromAsync(responseJSON);
          setFetched(true);
          setFetching(false);
          fetchMedusa();
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setFetching(false);
    }
  };
```

The problem comes when I implement the rules in firebase. Before this, I had everything open (read: true, write: true) but to add a bit of security I am trying to add this anonymous authentication. My rules now are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Once I put this rules the data cannot be retrieved. I get no data basically, and my console log says "Permission Denied".

What am I doing wrong? Should I pass the user ID with the fetch? Please help

Thanks very much

Comment: I don't see any call to the Firebase Realtime Database API in the code you shared. It's probably hidden behind one of the helper methods, but unfortunately it's impossible to say what is failing without seeing the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). External dependencies like your helper functions make it impossible to help.

Comment: I see.. could you explain how to pass the auth info to firebase in another case you know? Maybe it helps me understand. Thanks again

Comment: Solved it. Anyway thanks for answering. I have commented the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

The packages that come from React Native Firebase are ment to be used together. What was happening was:

**I was using the fetch method from react native. You have to use the firebase database package they give you to retrieve or write data.**

See how my fetch looks now:

```
 await database()
        .ref(setLocale())
        .once('value')
        .then(responseJSON => {
          if (responseJSON.error) {
            setFetching(false);
            setFetched(false);
          } else {
            saveFavoritesFromAsync(responseJSON.val());
            setFetched(true);
            setFetching(false);
            fetchMedusa();
          }
```

Also important, the responseJSON data has to be saved with the .val() method or it won't be correct.

I hope it can help someone in need.